# m2e additional config

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

When I use m2e plugin to build eclipse configuration files like `.classpath`, I need to write some additional config files.

In example I need to write a flex file `.actionScriptProperties`.

I can do this with the `maven-eclipse-plugin` with `additionalConfig` configuration but the integration with eclipse ide is not really good.

Can I do this with m2e?

Can I call eclipse goal in Update Project button?